# Animate till a certain index

Tags: iphone, animation

I have an array of 1000images.

I need to sometimes animate till a certain index, but not everytime. Is there a way to specify this in the [myImageView startAnimating]?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no control over the UIImageView's animation. You can either create another array and use it or you can write you own method to change the images using NSTimer.